# Customize devise controller and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I am naive in ROR. I am trying to login user with only email, using devise. I want to render login page if user with email provided does not exist. But, when I try to render 'new', after checking that user does not exist in database. While doing so I get error - "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance !!!

rails/app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Users sessions controller
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include ExpireExistingToken
  
  layout 'devise'

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    self.resource = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
    if resource.nil?
      render 'new'
    else
      set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      resource.update(language: Constant::SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.key(params['locale'])) if params['locale'].present?
      resource.send_otp(force_expire: true) if resource.email_verified?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      flash.delete(:notice)
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    session.delete(:is_otp_verified)
    super
  end
end
```

rails/app/controllers/concerns/expire_existing_token.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Responsible for token expiration
module ExpireExistingToken
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :remove_existing_token, only: :new
  end

  protected

  def remove_existing_token
    uuid = session[:uuid]
    usr = User.find_by(uuid: uuid) if uuid
    return unless usr
    usr.send(:clear_reset_password_token)
    usr.save
    session.delete(:uuid)
  end
end
```

rails/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.haml

```
.authentication-wrapper
  .gatway
    .brand-icon
      = image_pack_tag('packs/images/logo.png')
    .title
      Merchant Login
    .caption
      Make every moment special with WadzPay.
    = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name),
      html: { class: 'user-session-form new_user' }) do |f|
      .form-group
        = f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Enter Email Address',
                                                type: 'email', class: 'form-control'
        %span
          = image_pack_tag('packs/images/mail.svg')
      .auth-btn-set
        = f.button 'Log in', class: 'btn-primery-grdient w-100'
        %a.btn-white-link.w-100{href: "register.html"} Register
  .auth-footer
    %a{href: "#"} Terms &amp; Condition
    |
    %a{href: "#"} Privacy Policy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `render 'new'` will make your application load the `new` html, what you want in this case is to redirect your user to the registrations page.
Replacing `render 'new'` for `redirect_to action: :new` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` view display a form for the current `resource`, which should be initialized in the action `new`.

Your best bet at this point, is to replace `render 'new'` by calling `new` itself, which should take care of your problem.

Comment: Hi @geoffroy, I replaced `render 'new'`  with `new`. now I get error - 
` undefined method `users_url' for #<Users::SessionsController:0x007f963d917c08> Did you mean? user_session_url.`

 Am I doing it wrong??

Answer (score 0):

"render" only renders the template but if you want to gain the object access to perform some operation then "redirect_to" comes in picture.

So simply replace **render: new** to **redirect_to: new**